# Force Eclipse to treat .c files as C++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide

I'm working with an external project that uses `.c` file extension for C++ files (they will not change this, I have even sent them a full patch).

Is there any way to force Eclipse (autotools project) to index all `.c`/`.h` files as C++?

Comment: That seems stupid. The big compilers uses the file-ending to know what kind of language it's compiling. If a file is ending in `.c` then the compiler will compile it as a C source file, and if you're unlucky the compiler front-end program won't have an option to tell it otherwise.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, that is an extremely helpful comment.

Comment: you can convert all them to C++ , click project name then menu then New-> C++ project and then convert to and select C++ project.

Comment: There's `Preferences->C/C++->Language Mappings` where you apparently can tell Eclipse that C files are C++.  What it actually does, I don't know though.

Comment: @ameyCU This project will not show up in the list. Most likely because it is already a C++ project.

Comment: @nos This seems like it would be the right setting, it even re-runs the indexer if you change it, but `.c` files still don't see C++ headers.

Comment: Do you have problems only with the IDE, or is it problems when you are attempting to build the project? If it's the latter and you're using GCC try adding the option `-x c++` (which tells GCC to build as C++ instead of the deducted C).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Just the IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter in

`Preferences->C/C++->FileTypes`

You can see the file association there. It doesn't let me change it in my Eclipse Luna CDT, but what you can do is to override it per project.

`Properties->C/C++ General->FileTypes->Use project settings`

Comment: It's still complaining about unresolved includes, but the indexer seems to index the files correctly now.